# Making the usertype users staff simply

Tags: django

I have a usertype 1 as patient, 2 as Doctor. Now i neeed to create usertype 2 as a `is_staff=true` and assigned into a doctor group with its permission.

```
class UserType(models.Model):
user =models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
USER_TYPE = (
    (1, 'Patient'),
    (2, 'Doctor'),
)
user_type = models.IntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`signals`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/signals/) to add user to specific group whenever `UserType` object is saved and if `user_type` is 2:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from .models import UserType

def add_user_to_doctors_group(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.user_type == 2:
        doctors = Group.objects.get(name='doctors')
        doctors.user_set.add(instance.user)
        instance.user.is_staff = True
        instance.user.save()
post_save.connect(add_user_to_doctors_group, sender=UserType)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

User = get_user_model()
new_user_instance = User.objects.create_user(username='your_username', email='foo@bar.com', password='secret_password', is_staff=True)
user_type_instance = UserType.objects.create(user=new_user_instance, user_type=2)

group = Group.objects.get(name='groupname')
new_user_instance.groups.add(group)
```